# How to: Use java Set and Get

Tags: java

I am trying to create a **"Class": Sandwich.Java** and **"Application": testSandwich.java.**

*My task is to Include methods to get and set values for 3 fields in Sandwich.java:
Main Ingredient,Bread Type, Price.
Then with the application, that instantiate five Sandwich objects in an array. (Five Arrays)*

***Sandwich.java:***

```
public class Sandwich {
    public String mainIngredient = "";
    public String breadType = "";
    public Double price;   

    String getMainIngredient(){
        return mainIngredient;
    }

    void setMainIngredient(String mainIng){
        mainIngredient = mainIng;
    }

    void setBread(String wheat){
        breadType = wheat;
    }

    void setPrice(double mainPrice){
        price = mainPrice;
    }
```

***testSandwich.java:***

```
public class TestSandwich {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

                Sandwich[] sandwiches = new Sandwich[5];


                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                sandwiches[i] = new Sandwich();

                System.out.println("Choose a Main Ingredient: ");
                String userInput = user_input.next();
                sandwiches[i].setBread(userInput);

                System.out.println("Choose a Bread: ");
                userInput = user_input.next();
                sandwiches[i].setMainIngredient(userInput);

                System.out.println(sandwiches[i].getMainIngredient());
                System.out.println("");
```

***Current Error Output:***

Choose a Main Ingredient:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code 
- Erroneous sym type: user_input.next

```
at practical.TestSandwich.main(TestSandwich.java:24)
```

Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

***Question:*** How can I fix the error and How do I get the result I am looking for?

Comment: Firstly, I would strongly suggest that you don't try to run code that doesn't compile. Make sure your code compiles first - and if you're offered the option of running code that hasn't compiled properly, *say no* unless you've got a particular reason you want to run invalid code as far as possible.

Comment: As for this error - this has nothing to do with getter and setter methods... you're trying to call a method on a `user_input` variable, but you haven't declared that anyway. Perhaps you are missing `Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);` at the start of your `main` method? (I'd strongly advise you not to name variables using underscores, and *certainly* don't have variables called both `user_input` and `userInput` in the same method... very confusing.)

Comment: Where did you declare user_input ?

Comment: @JonSkeet Is something like this what you mean?: `Scanner user_input_mainIngredient = new Scanner(System.in);`                                                                   
                `String userInput = user_input_mainIngredient.next();`

Comment: @BravoTangoCC: No, I wouldn't do that. I'd probably use a separate variable for each input, e.g. `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); String ingredient = input.next(); ... String bread = input.next();` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Exeption is thrown because you didnt initiate a `Scanner user_input` at all. Try this at the start of your `main()` function:

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
```

here is an basic tutorial how to deal with Scanner objects and user input:
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/user_input.html

I also strongly recommend you, to do some research before youre posting your question. Also you should understand what your programm does otherwise you won't understand your problems at all(as it is this time).